# Consuming WCF in Xamarin.Forms with App.config

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is is possible to consume WCF service using App.config in Xamarin.Forms? In Xamarin.Forms I have PCL library and three platform projects: iOS, Android and Windows Phone.

Normally  (in WPF for example) I have App.config file with such content:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint
          address="net.tcp://localhost:8002/FooService"
          binding="netTcpBinding"
          contract="MyApp.Contracts.IFooService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

GameProxy class, like that:

```
public class GameProxy : ClientBase<IFooService>, IFooService
{
    public async Task<BarResponse> BarRequest(int id)
    {
        return await Channel.BarRequest(id);
    }
}
```

Is is possible to do it in such way in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no App.config file in Xamarin.  You simply need to set the values in code like this:

```
private static BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttp()
{
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
        {
            Name = "basicHttpBinding",
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
        };
    TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
    binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
    binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
    return binding;
}
```

The Xamarin documentation has a [complete WCF walkthrough](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/).

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look. Btw. Is netTcpBinding supported in Xamarin.Forms ?